# How get memory warning from android (skd) in Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

How get memory warning from android (skd) in Unity3d? I have big model, which loaing via assetbundles, I want unload some bunldes, if I got memory warning.

Comment: You can implement the [onLowMemory][1] callback in Android. 


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory%28%29

Comment: What add to android manifest?